# Make jquery Dialog non Postback from SelectedNodeChanged

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Im using the jquery dialog box and i am trying to stop the postback from happening when calling the dialog, so its basically handled on client side.

I am calling the dialog open from my Treeview's SelectedNodeChanged

```
protected void tvTreeList_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", string.Format("ParentNodeClick('{0}','{1}')", lblDescText, lblTitleText), true);
}
```

this is my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ParentNodeClick(Message, Title)
    {
        document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = Message;
        document.getElementById("dialog").title = Title;
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            width: 600,
            modal:true
        }); 
    };
</script>
```

Is there any way i can do this? Already tried to use this but it doesnt seem to work.

```
$("#dialog").parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
```

Full html on masterpage

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.master.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Web Data Source</title>
    <link href="Style/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="Style/jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ParentNodeClick(Message, Title)
        {
            document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = Message;
            document.getElementById("dialog").title = Title;
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                width: 600,
                modal:true
            });
        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="align-content:center; height:100%;">

        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

        <div id="dialog" title="">
          <p></p>
        </div>

        <div runat="server" style="text-align:center;">
            <h1 style="color:#505050;">Datastatus from Data servers</h1>
        </div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cphContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my treeview

```
<div id="TreeList">
            <asp:TreeView ID="tvTreeList" runat="server" OnSelectedNodeChanged="tvTreeList_SelectedNodeChanged" >
                <NodeStyle CssClass="NodeStyle"/>
                <HoverNodeStyle CssClass="HoverNodeStyle"/>
                <SelectedNodeStyle CssClass="SelectedNodeStyle" />
            </asp:TreeView>
        </div>
```

Comment: The postback is not caused by the dialog but for the `SelectedNodeChanged` of the TreeList. You have to open the dialog using jQuery by attaching the `click` event in each row of your Tree.

Comment: any chance you could give me an example how to add the click event using jquery?

Comment: Please, post your HTML code.

Comment: i made changes to the post, see above code